# module of a too long var in php

Tags: php, module, int, long-integer

How can i do to the module of a var that contents 24 digits in php

```
00120345030000067890142807 % 97
```

the result of this operation must be 1 but the problem is that the var that contains de value is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [BCMath PHP functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) to handle large numbers. Depending on your environment, the BCMath extension is often already bundled with PHP, you might be able to search for it in your package manager of choice if you're using Linux. If you're on an older version of PHP, let me know and I can hopefully show you how to compile the extension manually from the php source tree.

The function to use is `bcmod` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmod.php

You can use it like this:

```
<?php

$bigNumber = '00120345030000067890142807';

echo($bigNumber % 97 . "\n");
echo(bcmod($bigNumber, 97) . "\n");
```

If you run this, you'll see it outputs the expected result and that the standard mod doesn't:

```
$ php -q test.php
65
1
```